# TFS on VSTS: `tf vc unshelve <shelvesetname>` fails silently not downloading changes

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

Preparing new build definition working with TFS version control on VSTS I encountered strange beahaviour:

When doing a build from shelveset in log files I can see that sources from main repo are downloaded (and they are indeed) and later in logs there is information about unshelving changes from shelveset - but those files are not actually downloaded, what causes later pipeline tasks to fail.

Example logs:

```
2018-09-26T09:47:29.6580577Z ##[command]tf vc workspace /delete ws_5_23;1c4749a7-aba9-45f6-93c1-0b3c777d3de3 /collection:<collectionname>/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
2018-09-26T09:47:32.1224786Z ##[command]tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_5_23 /collection:<collectionname>/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
2018-09-26T09:47:33.8329522Z ##[command]tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:ws_5_23 $/ /collection:<collectionname>/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
2018-09-26T09:47:35.4446518Z ##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_5_23 $/<path> <path2> /collection:<collectionname>/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
2018-09-26T09:47:36.9498633Z ##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_5_23 $/<path3> <path4> /collection:<collectionname>/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
2018-09-26T09:47:38.6423920Z ##[command]tf vc get /version:50687 /recursive /overwrite C:\agent\_work\5\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
2018-09-26T09:47:41.5812148Z C:\agent\_work\5\s\Main\Source:
2018-09-26T09:47:41.5826483Z Getting BI
```

Later there are a lot of files that are downloaded - and they are actually downloaded, present on disk.

However, after this:

```
2018-09-26T09:47:46.3299164Z ##[command]tf vc unshelve <shelvesetname>;<user> /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
2018-09-26T09:47:48.5345961Z <path4>:
2018-09-26T09:47:48.5346886Z Unshelving edit: <solutionname>.sln
... and a lot of other changes from shelveset
```

Files that are specified to have been unshelved actually are not - they are not on disk. And pipeline fails later as it cannot find those files.

Few notes :

- unshelving those changes locally in Visual Studio 2017 proceeds as expected - files are downloaded to disk.
- changes are in two different parent folders each of which is mapped separately in build setting
- no error is thrown, it smoothly passes to another pipeline step

**How to make TFS actually download those changes from shelveset? Or is it just a TFS bug?**